# how to reset html textbox that allows number only using jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I want to reset textbox that allowing number only

```
$("#txtbox").val("");
```

above code not working as textbox allows number only.

Details:

I have one EmployeeID textbox which accepts only number (will not accept space also)

I want to reset/clear this textbox

Usually we do $("#your_id").val("");

i.e we replace value with blank value

But in my case this is not working as my textbox does not accept blank value.

So what can i use instead of .val("")

Comment: Works fine https://jsfiddle.net/bra2mwh0/  if it's not working for you please edit your question and add a snippet that *demonstrates* the problem - see [mcve].

Comment: Please can you explain a bit more about your question.

Comment: What do you mean "does not accept"? Is there some script or property which prevents the field from having an empty string as value? Also: What is the original initial value on page load before input is entered?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why would you do this, because you could simple do this in `HTML` by this

```
<input type = 'number'>
```

**Using JQuery**

```
 //html
 <input type="text" id = 'myIn'>
 <input type="button" value = 'click' id = 'bt'>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('#bt').click(function(){

 $('#myIn').attr('type', 'number');

});
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x94ndtcL/1/)

Comment: It is totally wrong to change the attribute of the input on click of the button in this case.

Comment: @KunalRaut the detais part was not given first, it's updated later, I will update my answer